# How to build an android kernel on windows machine

Tags: android, android-source

I want to build an android kernel on my windows machine. i am a beginner and i have just created some sample applications using eclipse and sdk. But now i want to learn what all the things we need for building an android kernel and how to build the kernel, how to configure the android kernel.

Comment: here is what you are looking for http://source.android.com/source/building-kernels.html

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for the same thing but I figured out that it's supported for Windows yet. As it says [here](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html): Building under Windows is not currently supported.

Answer (score 1):

use cygwin. that is linux simulator for windows